# How do you nock with aws-sdk-js credentials required in requests?

Tags: jestjs, aws-sdk-js, nock

I have jest unit tests using nock to intercept and return mock responses. I then re-run these during the integration test phase without nock so that it tests with the actual aws api and resources.

```
nock('https://ssm.us-west-1.amazonaws.com:443')
      .post('/', {"Name":"/my-parameter"})
      .reply(200, {"Parameter":{"ARN":"arn:aws:ssm:us-west-1:111222333444:parameter/my-parameter","DataType":"text","LastModifiedDate":1617149434.735,"Name":"/my-parameter","Type":"String","Value":"myvalue","Version":4}}, [
      'Server',
      'Server',
      'Date',
      'Thu, 08 Apr 2021 00:05:41 GMT',
      'Content-Type',
      'application/x-amz-json-1.1',
      'Content-Length',
      '284',
      'Connection',
      'keep-alive',
      'x-amzn-RequestId',
      '8885bb26-9018-4e9e-8b2e-56232e46ae17'
    ]).persist();
```

This works where my code runs and receives this response instead of the actual ssm resource. However, I still have to login and set my local credentials or it throws

```
    UnrecognizedClientException: The security token included in the request is invalid.

      at Request.extractError (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
      at Request.callListeners (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
      at Request.emit (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
      at Request.emit (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
      at Request.transition (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
      at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
      at node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
      at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
      at Request.callListeners (node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18)
```

I shouldn't need any aws credentials for running these mock unit tests. I don't see nock recording any other requests that I have to mock like a credential login. How can I set it to mock the credentials so that I don't need to so any actual aws api communication and this runs locally without an internet connection? I've been unable to find any examples so far. Any example of a project running unit tests that mock aws-sdk with nock would be great to reference!

Answer (score 0):

This question is incorrect. The NOCK_OFF environment variable was not getting set sometimes in this case and misleading to this question.

It does intercept the request. The client, nor the actual aws api, does not check the credentials set in the request when nock intercepts it.